# Как вытащить данные из excel файла представленного в виде массива байтов?

Tags: c#, excel, sdk, openxml

Добрый день!
Как я могу вытащить данные или скопировать `sheet` из excel-файла, представленного в виде массива байтов, используя [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Например, через MemoryStream и конструктор со стримом:

```
byte[] buffer = ...;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    var document = PresentationDocument.Create(
            ms,
            PresentationDocumentType.Presentation,
            autoSave: true /* или false */);
    // работаем как обычно
}
```